# Offline Access to Analytics Reporting API

Tags: javascript, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

my Google app gets the offline access this code of javascript library.

```
auth2.grantOffline().then(function(resp) {
     // where to use this auth_code? expiry of it?
    let auth_code = resp.code;
});
```

But I don't see any usage of this `auth_code`, is there any example/sample code to use it? what is the expiry date of this offline token code? Can we use this `auth_code` with PHP libarary?

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-php

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthgrantofflineaccessoptions

Thanks

Comment: This is(are) **[XY question(s)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)**! Only one question is allowed in the one post and you have 3 questions.